# Seam Faces causes a deploy-time error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam, cdi, seam3

I'm running a Java EE 6 application out of an EAR (bundling an EJB-JAR and a WAR) on GlassFish 3.0.1, using ICEfaces 2.0 Beta 1 and a Seam Faces 3.0.0 Alpha 3 Snapshot.

When I deploy the EAR, I get an error. **This error doesn't happen when I remove Seam Faces.** Here's the error from my GlassFish log (I redacted the first bit, where it just lists out my session beans and says that they have been transformed. I cut off the last few exceptions, because of StackOverflow's 30000-character limit.):

```
INFO: Loading application com.example.science_ScienceEar_ear_2.0.3-SNAPSHOT#ScheduleWeb-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT.war at /schedule
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) for context '/science'
WARNING: JSF1059: WARNING!  The com.sun.faces.verifyObjects feature is to aid developers not using tools.  It shouldn't be enabled if using an IDE, or if this application is being deployed for production as it will impact application start times.
INFO: Ajax Push Resource Handling not available: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/icepush/servlet/MainServlet
INFO: ICEsoft Technologies Inc.
ICEfaces 2.0.0 0.0.4 Beta1
Build number: 003
Revision: 21982

INFO: ICEfaces Configuration: org.icefaces.render.auto = true [default]  org.icefaces.autoid = true [default]  org.icefaces.aria.enabled = true [default]  org.icefaces.compressDOM = false [default]  
WARNING: ICEpush library missing. Push notification disabled.
INFO: Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308 Unable to resolve managed beans for Types: [class org.jboss.seam.faces.component.FormValidationTypeOverrideExtension]; Bindings: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:807)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:793)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:108)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:790)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:802)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:47)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:142)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:165)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:332)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.DependentContext.get(DependentContext.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:709)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:771)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:794)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:108)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:790)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:802)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:47)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:142)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:165)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:332)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractMapContext.get(AbstractMapContext.java:112)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyMethodHandler.getProxiedInstance(ClientProxyMethodHandler.java:143)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ClientProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.CleanableMethodHandler.invoke(CleanableMethodHandler.java:43)
        at org.jboss.seam.faces.environment.SeamApplicationWrapper_$$_javassist_27.installWrapper(SeamApplicationWrapper_$$_javassist_27.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:304)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:298)
        at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:200)
        at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:59)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:194)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:216)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:654)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:647)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:641)
        at org.jboss.seam.faces.event.SystemEventBridge.processEvent(SystemEventBridge.java:80)
        at org.jboss.seam.faces.event.DelegatingSystemEventListener.processEvent(DelegatingSystemEventListener.java:51)
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:1993)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:1969)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:299)
        at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:679)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:601)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:344)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4664)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5266)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

SEVERE: PWC1306: Startup of context /science failed due to previous errors
SEVERE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:892)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5456)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:530)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5284)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! WELD-001308 Unable to resolve managed beans for Types: [class org.jboss.seam.faces.component.FormValidationTypeOverrideExtension]; Bindings: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5289)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! WELD-001308 Unable to resolve managed beans for Types: [class org.jboss.seam.faces.component.FormValidationTypeOverrideExtension]; Bindings: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:354)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4664)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5266)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308 Unable to resolve managed beans for Types: [class org.jboss.seam.faces.component.FormValidationTypeOverrideExtension]; Bindings: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:807)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:793)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:108)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:790)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:802)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:47)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:142)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:165)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:332)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.DependentContext.get(DependentContext.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:709)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:771)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:794)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:108)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:790)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:802)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:47)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:142)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:165)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:332)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractMapContext.get(AbstractMapContext.java:112)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyMethodHandler.getProxiedInstance(ClientProxyMethodHandler.java:143)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ClientProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.CleanableMethodHandler.invoke(CleanableMethodHandler.java:43)
        at org.jboss.seam.faces.environment.SeamApplicationWrapper_$$_javassist_27.installWrapper(SeamApplicationWrapper_$$_javassist_27.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:304)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:298)
        at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:200)
        at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:59)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:194)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:216)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:654)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:647)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:641)
        at org.jboss.seam.faces.event.SystemEventBridge.processEvent(SystemEventBridge.java:80)
        at org.jboss.seam.faces.event.DelegatingSystemEventListener.processEvent(DelegatingSystemEventListener.java:51)
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:1993)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:1969)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:299)
        at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:679)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:601)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:344)
        ... 42 more
...
```

What gives? I've searched the web for this exception, and it looks like it happens when CDI is enabled on both an EJB-JAR and a WAR packaged inside a single EAR, but only my WAR has CDI enabled (only it has a beans.xml). I tried moving the dependency up to the EAR, but I just get a different exception then.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this trace, I'm guessing that something is preventing proper discovery of beans when CDI starts up. Based on the fact that the issue only appears when Seam Faces is on the ClassPath, I'd have to say I'm not sure what.

Which version of Seam Faces are you using? 3.0.0.Alpha3 shouldn't have any problems on GF 3.0.1-b22

Comment: I upgraded to GlassFish 3.1b25 (from 3.0.1b22) and the latest Seam Faces 3.0.0 snapshot (October 23, 2010) and am getting different errors now; I'll let you know how it works. Now I'm getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger on deploy.

Comment: Ok, the answer to this is to include JBoss logging - which is the new logging solution for Seam, we are no longer using SLF4j, so you need to include:

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Beta4</version>
</dependency>

Comment: <repository>
  <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</repository>

Comment: Thank you, Lincoln! (I assume you meant 3.0.0.Beta4, not 1.0.0.Beta4). That clears up the logging issue, but I'm still getting the original WELD-001308 error. I'm also getting a few other new errors, all of which look like they have something to do with class loading. I'll work on it a bit and keep you abreast of what I've found.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your classpath? Based on what you have above it looks like while trying to load the class `org.icepush.servlet.MainServlet` it failed while trying to look up the class `org.jboss.seam.faces.component.FormValidationTypeOverrideExtension`. Do you have the jar that contains this class in your EAR? Is it at the right level for your application to find it? (ie, EAR level, WAR level, in the WAR lib dir, etc.)

Usually when I get a ClassNotFoundException it is because I am missing a jar, or the jar is at the wrong location within my app so it can't load it appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The WAR is getting org.jboss.seam.faces.component.FormValidationTypeOverrideExtension through the Seam Faces JAR; I can't see anything wrong there. As far as org.icepush.servlet.MainServlet is concerned, it's just a warning that an optional feature of ICEfaces is disabled. I tried enabling it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Nick - where in your application is the jar located? That might be part of it. The other thing I started to think of was the fact that Seam likes to do dependency injection. I'm not familiar with ICEFaces, although I know it to be another JSF implementation. Does it also attempt to do dependency injection? Just wondering because I am reminded of some articles I read in the past about Seam and Spring and how to config them so they don't conflict with each other as each wants to be the main dependency injector. Not sure if you have that going on here to or not? Just some other thoughts.

Comment: The JAR is bundled with the WAR. As far as I know, ICEfaces doens't implement JSF; it uses Mojarra, and it doesn't do dependency injection. Thanks!